# SnackBar allow the certain space from the bottom bar

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am using `SnackBar` for single line message for related operation.

```
Snackbar snackBar;
public void showSnackBar(View view){
    snackBar = Snackbar.make(view, "Searching for GPS", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackBar.show();
}
```

In the method `isGPSEnabled` , i use the method `showSnackBar`

```
if(Helper.isGPSEnabled(this)){
            showSnackBar(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
}
```

But I got this,

[image: this]

Why `SnackBar` allow some space from bottom bar ?

**Edit**

The layout file :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
    android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingEnd="0dip"
/>

<AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I do not know the reason why, but maybe `snackbar.getView().setTranslationY(25f);` solves this issue. From @DennyWeinberg https://stackoverflow.com/a/61599387/4300670

Answer (score 0):

Please check `android.R.id.content` view in your layout file. 
SnackBar will be shown at the bottom of this view if it is FrameLayout. If you have added padding try removing it.

Can help you better, if you share the layout code.

Comment: As per your code app should crash. Because `android.R.id.content` is different from `android:id="@+id/content"`. Try changing `findViewById(R.id.content)` or  `android:id="@android:id/content"`

Comment: How do i need to call that `showSnackBar` method in `isGPSEnabled` method ?

Answer (score 0):

change 'content' Linear layout_height = "match_parent"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
    android:divider="@android:drawable/divider_horizontal_textfield"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true">
```

add answer. try this.

in xml linear id change

```
android:id="@+id/content" to android:id="@+id/parentLinear"
```

and code

```
LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.parentLinear);
Snackbar.make(linear, "Searching for GPS", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
```

Comment: try add answer.